# python pool apply_async and map_async do not block on full queue

Tags: python, design-patterns, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am fairly new to python.
I am using the multiprocessing module for reading lines of text on stdin, converting them in some way and writing them into a database. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
batch = []
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
i = 0
for i, content in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    batch.append(content)
    if len(batch) >= 10000:
        pool.apply_async(insert, args=(batch,i+1))
        batch = []
pool.apply_async(insert, args=(batch,i))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Now that all works fine, until I get to process huge input files (hundreds of millions of lines) that i pipe into my python program. At some point, when my database gets slower, I see the memory getting full.

After some playing, it turned out that pool.apply_async as well as pool.map_async never ever block, so that the queue of the calls to be processed grows bigger and bigger.

What is the correct approach to my problem? I would expect a parameter that I can set, that will block the pool.apply_async call, as soon as a certain queue length has been reached. AFAIR in Java one can give the ThreadPoolExecutor a BlockingQueue with a fixed length for that purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: _"it turned out that pool.apply_async as well as pool.map_async never ever block"_ - everything I was looking for

Answer (score 13):

The `apply_async` and `map_async` functions are designed not to block the main process. In order to do so, the `Pool` maintains an internal `Queue` which size is unfortunately impossible to change.

The way the problem can be solved is by using a `Semaphore` initialized with the size you want the queue to be. You acquire and release the semaphore before feeding the pool and after a worker has completed the task.

Here's an example working with Python 2.6 or greater.

```
from threading import Semaphore
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task_wrapper(f):
    """Python2 does not allow a callback for method raising exceptions,
    this wrapper ensures the code run into the worker will be exception free.

    """
    try:
        return f()
    except:
        return None

class TaskManager(object):
    def __init__(self, processes, queue_size):
        self.pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        self.workers = Semaphore(processes + queue_size)

    def new_task(self, f):
        """Start a new task, blocks if queue is full."""
        self.workers.acquire()
        self.pool.apply_async(task_wrapper, args=(f, ), callback=self.task_done))

    def task_done(self):
        """Called once task is done, releases the queue is blocked."""
        self.workers.release()
```

Another [example](https://gist.github.com/noxdafox/4150eff0059ea43f6adbdd66e5d5e87e) using `concurrent.futures` pools implementation.

Comment: In my case `task_done` needs to take arguments otherwise it will raise ValueError. Maybe it will be safer to change to `task_done(self, *args, **kwargs)` ?

Answer (score 11):

Just in case some one ends up here, this is how I solved the problem: I stopped using multiprocessing.Pool. Here is how I do it now:

```
#set amount of concurrent processes that insert db data
processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2

#setup batch queue
queue = multiprocessing.Queue(processes * 2)

#start processes
for _ in range(processes): multiprocessing.Process(target=insert, args=(queue,)).start() 

#fill queue with batches    
batch=[]
for i, content in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    batch.append(content)
    if len(batch) >= 10000:
        queue.put((batch,i+1))
        batch = []
if batch:
    queue.put((batch,i+1))

#stop processes using poison-pill
for _ in range(processes): queue.put((None,None))

print "all done."
```

in the insert method the processing of each batch is wrapped in a loop that pulls from the queue until it receives the poison pill:

```
while True:
    batch, end = queue.get()
    if not batch and not end: return #poison pill! complete!
    [process the batch]
print 'worker done.'
```

Comment: Nice simple example.  Multiprocessing's pool is frequently more trouble than it is worth, especially since creating your own process pool is quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

`apply_async` returns an [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object, which you can `wait` on:

```
if len(batch) >= 10000:
    r = pool.apply_async(insert, args=(batch, i+1))
    r.wait()
    batch = []
```

Though if you want to do this in a cleaner manner, you should use a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) with a `maxsize` of 10000, and derive a `Worker` class from `multiprocessing.Process` that fetches from such a queue.

Comment: well waiting on the AsyncResult does not help as my problem is that the queue in the Pool grows to large. I wonder if I can control the size of the internal queue in the pool?

Comment: @konstantin: I'm not sure I understand. While you're waiting for the `AsyncResult`, the master process can't fill the next batch, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but you can access the internal queue size and wait until it's below your maximum desired size before adding new items:

```
max_pool_queue_size = 20

for i in range(10000):
  pool.apply_async(some_func, args=(...))

  while pool._taskqueue.qsize() > max_pool_queue_size:
    time.sleep(1)
```